# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable for xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, nonetype, xmltodict

```
for i in range(1,3200):
    input_file = 'ProductGet'
    fp = open(input_file+str(i)+'.xml' ,encoding='utf8')
    tree = etree.parse(fp)
    ProductID = tree.xpath('/Responses/Response/Data/Product/ProductID/text()')
    with open(input_file+str(i)+'.xml', errors='ignore') as fd:
        doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    berrak = doc['Responses']['Response']['Data']['Product']
    for ii in range(0,len(ProductID)):
        print(berrak[ii]['Variations']['Variation']['VariationIsLive'])
```

I have some .xml file sets and my script is opening all of them from 1 to 3200. But when it is parsing it randomly it shows `NoneType` message for `berrak[ii]['Variations']['Variation']['VariationIsLive']` this part. I checked this file, everything look good. my question is how can i convert to this NoneType elements to strings?

Comment: Basically you need to check if that element exists in XML before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You should protect your code from this issue

```
for ii in range(0,len(ProductID)):
    variations = berrak[ii].get('Variations')
    if variations:
        variation = variations.get(''Variation'')
        if variation:
            is_live = variation.get('VariationIsLive')
            if is_live is not None:
                print(is_live)
```

Comment: Great. See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if you want to accept the answer.